# Docker volume specification

Tags: docker

When I use the below commands in docker volume specification:

1. `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v /home/ec2-user/jenkins_backup:/var/jenkins_home jenkins:2.60.1`
2. `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v /home/ec2-user/jenkins_backup:/var/jenkins_home jenkins`

... the following error is shown:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dreamy_hugle (5bd895eec77a2df5152a012fada4eeaf832daf4258307e6fab3961b9a151fba7): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use.
```

The jenkins will pull but the jenkins_backup volume is not being created.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It seems like the error is not in volumes, but because something else is running on port 8080. Please post output of `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`.

Comment: You can fix the port by using this option: `-p xxxx:8080`, where `xxxx` is the new port you want to map on the outside of the container.